# Is there a way to specify that elements are unique taking into consideration the values of the attributes?

Tags: xsd

Is there a way to specify that elements are unique taking into consideration the values of the attributes?

```
<fruit>orange</fruit> <!-- valid -->
<fruit>apple</fruit> <!-- valid -->
<fruit>apple</fruit> <-- invalid, duplicate value -->
<fruit color=green">apple</fruit> <!-- valid, because attributes are different -->
<fruit color=red">apple</fruit> <!-- valid, because attributes are different -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XSD 1.1 Solution

This can be solved in XSD 1.1 using assertions. This example assertion test that every colored fruit is the only fruit with that color and name, and tests that every uncolored fruit is the only fruit with that name and no color:

```
<assert test="every $fruit in ./fruit satisfies
    if ($fruit/@color)
        then count(fruit[@color=$fruit/@color and text()=$fruit/text()])=1
    else
        count(fruit[text()=$fruit/text() and not(@color)])=1"/>
```

---

I don't think this can be done directly using *xs:unique* in XSD 1.0 because of the limited XPath subset allowed.